# How to add a set of alphanumeric contents into a list using python?

Tags: python, regex, list, append

I have a log file with date,time,process name and packet data in alphanumeric format separated by space.

A sample line:

```
Date Time ProcessName ActivityName : 55 34 00 aa c9 00 11 45 55
```

I wrote a regex to parse the content and get the packet data. Now I want these packet data to be stored in a list so that I can write a comparison script to compare this with a new list. I created a new list and used append inside a for loop to append each element of the packet data. I expected to see my list like **['55','34','00','c9','00','11','45','55]** but I am getting **['5','','5','','3','','4','','0','','0' and so on]**.

The for loop I used:

```
for packs in match.group(6):
       list.append(packs)
```

How should I get the list populated with the value in a format I wanted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `re.findall` function.

```
re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z\d]{2}(?!\S)', string)
```

**Example:**

```
>>> s = "Date Time ProcessName ActivityName : 55 34 00 aa c9 00 11 45 55"
>>> re.findall(r'(?<!\S)[A-Za-z\d]{2}(?!\S)', s)
['55', '34', '00', 'aa', 'c9', '00', '11', '45', '55']
```

**Explanation:**

- `(?<!\S)` Negative lookbehind asserts that the match won't be preceded by a non-space character.
- `[a-z\d]{2}` Matches lowercase alphabets or digits exactly two times.
- `(?!\S)` Negative lookahead asserts that the match won't be followed by a non-space character.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks :) I started the regex with findall but then I have a different activity name that I have to find out before processing the packet data. Now that I have done it, I included this findall inside the if condition of the pattern match with the regex I already had written out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this per line

```
line = "Date Time ProcessName ActivityName : 55 34 00 aa c9 00 11 45 55"

new_list = line.split(':')[1].split()
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate over a string will give one character at a time. You will have to split the string first:

```
>>> data.split()
['55', '34', '00', 'aa', 'c9', '00', '11', '45', '55']
```

You can also precise the separator:

```
>>> data.split(' ')
['55', '34', '00', 'aa', 'c9', '00', '11', '45', '55']
```

If you want to use regexp, see Avinash Raj's answer. Otherwise, it's possible to get the number only with splitting if the form of the line is always the same:

```
>>> line.split(' : ')[1].split(' ')
['55', '34', '00', 'aa', 'c9', '00', '11', '45', '55']
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd better use string for comparing. You may use

```
...
list.append(...)
DATA=''.join(list)
```

Then you'll get a string like this: '553400c90011...'

Answer (score 0):

Just modify your old regex and add `[0].split()` to get the result you want.

```
import re
x="Date Time ProcessName ActivityName : 55 34 00 aa c9 00 11 45 55"
print re.findall(r"(?<=:)\s*([\da-zA-Z]{2}(?:\s[\da-zA-Z]{2})*)",x)[0].split()
```

Output:`['55', '34', '00', 'aa', 'c9', '00', '11', '45', '55']`

Try this.This will give you list of what you want.